# Change from using fetch to fs.readFile or require

Tags: reactjs, fetch, require, fs

I am unable to use fetch within our react app due to it being packaged within electron.  I am trying to find a way to modify what we have to either use `fs.readFile` or `require`. From what I have read it would be better to use require as it would already be parsed as JSON?

This is my current code:

```
fetch('./build/config.json')
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((json) =>{
          //console.log(json);
          //json defines the module NavLink s and their content - so save it to App state
          for (var n=0 ; n<json.nlinks.length ; n++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].state = (n===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
            json.nlinks[n].currentChapter = 0; // create field dynamically
            if (json.nlinks[n].chapters)
            {
              if (!json.nlinks[n].test) json.nlinks[n].test={state:0,submitted:0,title:"dummy",questions:[]}; // create dummy test dynamically
              for (var q=0 ; q<json.nlinks[n].test.questions.length ; q++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].response=0;
                json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].correct=false;
              }
              for (var c=0 ; c<json.nlinks[n].chapters.length ; c++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].state = (c===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
                if (json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections)
                {
                  json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].currentSection=0; 
                  for (var s=0 ; s<json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections.length ; s++)
                  {
                    json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections[s].state = (s===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections=[];
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters=[];
            }
          }
          this.setState({config: json,});

          });
```

**Updated Code based on @Marcin answer:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      config:{
        nlinks:[],
        },
        numPages: null,
        pageNumber: 1,
      popup: null,
      pdf:null,
      homelhs:"",
      homerhs:"",
      currentNlink:0,
      currentClink:0
      };



      const json = require('../public/config.json');
      console.log(json);
      //json defines the module NavLink s and their content - so save it to App state
      for (var n=0 ; n<json.nlinks.length ; n++)
      {
        json.nlinks[n].state = (n===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
        json.nlinks[n].currentChapter = 0; // create field dynamically
        if (json.nlinks[n].chapters)
        {
          if (!json.nlinks[n].test) json.nlinks[n].test={state:0,submitted:0,title:"dummy",questions:[]}; // create dummy test dynamically
          for (var q=0 ; q<json.nlinks[n].test.questions.length ; q++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].response=0;
            json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].correct=false;
          }
          for(var c=0 ; c<json.nlinks[n].chapters.length ; c++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].state = (c===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
            if (json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections)
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].currentSection=0; 
              for (var s=0 ; s<json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections.length ; s++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections[s].state = (s===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
              }
            }
            else
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections=[];
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          json.nlinks[n].chapters=[];
        }
      }
      this.setState({config: json,});

      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
//      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
```

Error I am getting:

> react.development.js:188 Warning: Can't call setState on a component
>   that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug
>   in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or
>   define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the
>   App component.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `require`. Your code would be changed as following:

```js
const json = require('./build/config.json');
//console.log(json);
//json defines the module NavLink s and their content - so save it to App state
for (var n=0 ; n<json.nlinks.length ; n++)
{
  json.nlinks[n].state = (n===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
  json.nlinks[n].currentChapter = 0; // create field dynamically
  if (json.nlinks[n].chapters)
  {
    if (!json.nlinks[n].test) json.nlinks[n].test={state:0,submitted:0,title:"dummy",questions:[]}; // create dummy test dynamically
    for (var q=0 ; q<json.nlinks[n].test.questions.length ; q++)
    {
      json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].response=0;
      json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].correct=false;
    }
    for(var c=0 ; c<json.nlinks[n].chapters.length ; c++)
    {
      json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].state = (c===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
      if (json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections)
      {
        json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].currentSection=0; 
        for (var s=0 ; s<json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections.length ; s++)
        {
          json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections[s].state = (s===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
        }
      }
      else
      {
        json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections=[];
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    json.nlinks[n].chapters=[];
  }
}
this.setState({config: json,});
```

However if you wish to stay with fetch (better solution as it is promise-based), you can import a polyfill as nodejs does not support it: [fetch polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch). All your fetches wouldnt have to be touched as it follows the same structure as `window.fetch`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only have a single fetch so I think using the `require` method will be suitable. I will put this in and test it :)

Comment: Managed to get config.json to be loaded but I am getting this error now when using require: react.development.js:188 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component.

Comment: I tried using the polyfill but i get the same file scheme error once it is packaged up

Comment: As the error states, you cannot use `this.setState` before the component gets mounted. You are calling it in the constructor (which is ran before the component gets mounted). If you wish to perform the code after the mount, put it in the `componentDidMount` method. However if you wish the `state` to be filled with your data before the mount just replace `this.setState({config: json,});` with `this.state.config = json`

Comment: I managed to put this one within the `componentDidMount` however I found others that another developer had in place which cannot be put in the `componentDidMount` so I have tried using the `this.state.homerhs` however I get `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'`

Comment: This has changed in a completely unrelated question. I don't know how your colleagues code looks like so I cannot help. Please consider this question answered and open a new question or contact me privately (I'll be glad to help)